# ionic (2 or 3) multi select spinner with check box and search

Tags: ionic2, html-select, ionic3

How to  make drop down  which has search and and checkbox with multiple   selection similar to this image .this image for just reference

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple="true" in ion-select i share the html code 
i follow this link :- http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple="true" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!">
          <ion-option value="bacon" selected="true">Bacon</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="olives">Black Olives</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="xcheese" selected="true">Extra Cheese</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="peppers">Green Peppers</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="onions">Onions</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="pineapple">Pineapple</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="sausage">Sausage</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="Spinach">Spinach</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: follow this link to search data 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#searchbar

Comment: this is search bar there are no select and checkbox or radio

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can achieve it by using the popover component for the select component. Check the SELECT component API it explains how you can use a popover instead of an AlertController for your select. Then use the popover to add the search box at the top. Or just use a modal and return an array or selected elements back through the NavParams. Josh Morony has a good video on youtube and explains how to use a modal to pass parameters backwards and forwards. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful Cordova plugin that allows you to utilize the features you're wanting with ion-search. This plugin is more relevant to Ionic 3, but I'm assuming the plugin works for Ionic 2 as well.

[ionic-selectable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-select-searchable) plugin via npm. More info on the Plugin components and features,https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable.

A visual on what you may be looking for:

[image]

The link provides the structure of how the plugin is utilized in your project. There are actually quite a few features that may even be useful for different scenarios as well.